# dc.js BarChart yAxis range plus padding

Tags: d3.js, dc.js

I have a stack barchart and added an outline to the bars via

```
.dc-chart rect.bar {stroke: black;}
```

I have also defined

```
.elasticY(true)
```

The black outline at the top of the bar (xAxis 0) is chopped by a pixel compared to the top of the bar (xAxis 2).  Is there anyway to pad the y max range by a little so I can see the outline and still keep elasticY?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strangely enough, it's called `yAxisPadding`, [and it's documented here](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/develop/web/docs/api-latest.md#dc.coordinateGridMixin+yAxisPadding). It does work with `elasticY`.

I guess the Markdown documentation is getting a little long to just browse. The [HTML documentation](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.coordinateGridMixin.html) is better if you know the particular class or mixin where the function might be defined. (Takes some practice.)

You can use either a number, in domain units:

```
chart.yAxisPadding(10)
```

or a percentage, as a string:

```
chart.yAxisPadding("5%")
```

Padding in domain units [can lead to some surprises, though](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/1120).

Comment: Exactly what I needed.  I will spend some quality time with the API documentation now that I have coded several examples using our data and am slowing getting it. Thanks again.

Comment: `yAxisPadding` adds space both above *and* below the bars, however--you can overwrite `yAxisMin` with a function that always returns 0 to compensate.